# Python method like File.WriteAllBytes() in .Net

Tags: python, .net, file-handling

There is a .net API sending the byte data as a string in JSON, I am using a python API to read it and write it in a file.

```
a = io.BytesIO(b"JVBERi0xLjQNJcjIyMjIyMg...")
with open('test.pdf','wb') as g:
    g.write(a.getvalue())
```

I created a file with this code but unable to open the file.
I need another way of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using io.BytesIO use base64.

```
import base64
data = "strin data"
base64_data =base64.b64decode(data)
with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64_data)
```